# c# 4 deserialize JSON complex object list<int>

Tags: list, c#-4.0, serialization

Happy New Year :-)

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
\"OutcomeSummaryID\":105,
\"DeliveryDetailsID\":9,
\"AttemptedDeliveryModesIDList\":[1,5],
}
```

And I am using the following method to deserialize it:

```
private void SerializeModel<T>(IDictionary<string, object> dataModel, T myModel)
    {
        Type sourceType = typeof(T);
        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in (sourceType.GetProperties()))
        {
            if (dataModel.ContainsKey(propInfo.Name))
            {
                //  if an empty string has been returned don't change the value
                if (dataModel[propInfo.Name].ToNullSafeString() != String.Empty)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Type localType = propInfo.PropertyType;
                        localType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(localType) ?? localType;                            
                        propInfo.SetValue(myModel, Convert.ChangeType(dataModel[propInfo.Name], localType), null);                            
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //  ToDo: log serialize value errors
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The model definition is:

```
public class DeliveryDetailsView
{
    public int OutcomeSummaryID { get; set; }
    public int DeliveryDetailsID { get; set; }
    public List<int> AttemptedDeliveryModesIDList { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this is get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
Message=Object must implement IConvertible.
```

This is an extract from a larger project and I have used this method extensively elsewhere but this is the first time with a list as a field and I can see no clean way to resolve this. I could use

```
if (localType.IsCollectionType())
```

but don't know where to proceed after that.(None of the answers from Google seem to fit this situation and most relate to XML).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Cube below I now have a partial answer.

```
 if (localType.IsGenericType && localType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(List<>)))
{   
    Type localListType = localType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if (localListType.Equals(typeof(int)))
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> dataItem = (Dictionary<string, object>)dataModel[propInfo.Name];
        List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in dataItem)
        {
            tempList.Add((int)item.Value);
        }
        propInfo.SetValue(perinatalModel, tempList,  null);
    }
}
```

... However, all attempts to convert the JSON array to a List have failed. I have also attempted

```
List<int> tempList = (List<int>)dataModel[propInfo.Name];
```

Both throw the exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' ...
```

Any further thoughts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a similar problem some time ago. I had to treat non primitive types in special way like this:

```
if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(List<>)))
{
    Type u = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    if (u.Equals(typeof(int)))
       // now dealing with List<int>
...
}
```

hope this short snippet helps.

**Update** to the Update:

```
if (localListType.Equals(typeof(int)))
{
    object[] dataItem = (object[])dataModel[propInfo.Name];
    List<int>tempList = new List<int>();
    foreach(object probablyInteger in dataItem)
        tempList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(probablyInteger));
    propInfo.SetValue(perinatalModel, tempList,  null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this start; what I really (really) need is how to deal with extracint the JSON into the list<int> field of my model

Comment: dataModel[propInfo.Name] should be something enumerable. I think you have to iterate through it and bulid a List<int> from it. Probaly as simple as `new List<int>(dataModel[propInfo.Name])`. This list should be suitable for `propInfo.SetValue`. `ChangeType` will not do this work for you.

Comment: Now having trouble creating the list - see update above. Thanks again for all help.

Comment: Since i don't know what `dataModel[propInfo.Name]` actually is i cannot say how to cast it. Due to the error message i would try `object[] tempList = (object[])dataModel[propInfo.Name]`. The object's itself hopefully are or can be converted to integers.

Comment: The final suggestion completed the solution perfectly - many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code

```
public List<int> AttemptedDeliveryModesIDList { get; set; }
```

with

```
public int[] AttemptedDeliveryModesIDList { get; set; }
```

I haven't tried the code. So I am not 100% sure

Comment: Thanks for this; I was hoping to get something on how to use with a list. If all else fails then I will certainly try this.